# gradle-clover-plugin to get code coverage from separate module

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, clover

I was tasked with splitting up a spring boot application to have multiple modules to look something like this:

- root

  - app

    - build.gradle
  - rest

    - build.gradle
  - service

    - build.gradle
  - dao

    - build.gradle
  - model

    - build.gradle
  - build.gradle
  - settings.gradle

Note: there is no code folder in the root of the project. Each module has its own `src` root

Before splitting the code into modules, the gradle-clover-plugin was showing that we had 95% code coverage, but due to the way that the tests are now organized, the plugin is not able to see that some of the code is being tested in other modules

For instance some of the `service` Class methods are being tested from the `rest` module while testing the controllers.

Looking thru the documentation for the plugin (https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-clover-plugin/blob/master/README.md), they mention specifying `additionalSourceSets` and `additionalTestSourceSets` in the `example` towards the bottom of the page, but it's not clear to me how to use those in my project

I added the following block from the example to my root `build.gradle`:

```
    additionalSourceSet {
        srcDirs = sourceSets.generatedCode.java.srcDirs
        classesDir = sourceSets.generatedCode.java.outputDir
    }
    additionalTestSourceSet {
        srcDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.java.srcDirs
        classesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.java.outputDir
    }
```

but was getting the following exception: Could not get unknown property 'generatedCode' for SourceSet container of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetContainer.

I then tried swapping out **generatedCode** and **integrationTest** with the names of my modules in the root `build.gradle` but was getting the same exception

Finally I tried specifying those properties in the build.gradle for the module, but was getting the following exception: Could not find method additionalSourceSets() for arguments on object of type com.bmuschko.gradle.clover.CloverPluginConvention

Is it indeed possible to specify another modules' sources for the plugin to consider when generating the code coverage report for a different module?

Comment: I would like to help, but i don't get it yet in total. Which java version, which gradle version, which plugin version?

Does the sourceSets know the generatedCode? The easiest way is to add some output, to see your configuration as a small debug. Sounds like, that generatedCode didn't happen yet.